# How to create two NSTtableView in one View?

Tags: macos, swift, nstableview

I have one NSTableView (for OSX, not iOS), and in my ViewController class, which datasource for this table, I have two functions to fill this table:

```
 func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
 func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

Everything is fine with this table. But I need another NSTableView in the same View. What I should do to have second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the identifier of each table. Inside your delegates; numberofRowsInTable etc, check for which table triggered the call like this;

```
    if aTableView.identifier == "table1Identifier"
    {
        // handle table 1 here
    }
    else
        ....
```

then return values for the correct table as needed.